# I have some trouble with pygame

Tags: pygame

I want "ball.giff" turn around the screen like this.

```
--->            -->
                   |
^                  v
|             

                   |
^                   v
|     <--      <- -
```

and my codes :

```
import sys
import pygame

size = width, height = 600, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("wedding")

brade = pygame.image.load("ball.gif")
brade_rect = brade.get_rect()
speed = [10, 0]
black = 0, 0, 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    brade_rect.move_ip(speed)
    if brade_rect.right>width:
        speed = [0,10]
    if brade_rect.bottom>height:
        speed = [-10, 0]
    if brade_rect.left<0:
        speed = [0, -10]
    if brade_rect.top<0:
        speed = [10, 0]

    pygame.time.delay(100)
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(brade, brade_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

but there is a problem. after one tour, ball go to right forever. It does not go to down?
What I missed, please can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the first turn, `brad_rect.top` becomes `-10`. You change the speed to `[10, 0]` but keep `brad_rect.top` to `-10` therefore the last if still activate and erase whatever of can be in speed. You should put back `brade_rect` in the window:

```
if brade_rect.right>width:
    speed = [0,10]
    brade_rect.right=width
if brade_rect.bottom>height:
    speed = [-10, 0]
    brade_rect.bottom=height
if brade_rect.left<0:
    speed = [0, -10]
    brade_rect.left=0
if brade_rect.top<0:
    speed = [10, 0]
    brade_rect.top=0
```

By the way, you should consider putting some `else` here.

Comment: Just adding a few print would have let you saw the problem !

Comment: yea, I was thinking that :) right way, by the way I'm so sorry for my bad English